# CMake generator for Clang on Windows

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm trying to build a simple C++ project on Windows 10 using Clang version 9.0.0. I can run the following command successful.

```
clang++ main.cpp -o learn.exe
```

This produces `learn.exe` which run successful. I need to be able to run something like this.

```
cmake -G "Clang Makefiles" ..
```

and then ...

```
make
```

As of current CMake, version 3.15 (even 3.16.0-rc3), there is no Clang generator for CMake that I know. Are there CMake generators for Clang or am I missing something?

Comment: CMake generators correspond to build systems. Clang is a compiler, not a build system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selecting the compiler is not done at the generator level, it's done by setting variables to CMake:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++ ..
```

Comment: OK. What would the generator be in this case?

Comment: The one you want to use. Personally I like `Ninja`, it's very fast and lean compared to makefiles.